# pnpm uses old version of node

Tags: npm, nvm, pnpm

I am using nvm and I got node v14 installed and running `node -v` confirms that, but when I try to install a package in my project that requires the v14 engine `pnpm` tells me that I am currently using node v12 `Unsupported engine: wanted: {"node":">=14.15"} (current: {"node":"v12.18.3","pnpm":"6.0.1"})` . This is the node version installed at `/usr/bin/node` but how do I tell it to use nvm version?

Comment: maybe try to remove pnpm manually and then reinstall it using the standalone script: `curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.js | node - add --global pnpm`

Comment: This worked. Though in my case, I had to restart the terminal session before the warning went away.

Answer (score 4):

Pnpm supports the [use-node-version](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#use-node-version) parameter, that will download and use a specific version of node.

You should remove or update this settings from your `.npmrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

Try running:

```
pnpm env use --global 14
```

And then:

```
pnpm add -g pnpm
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, `use-node-version` is a hack as it forces a specific version vs say `lts` or anything above the requested version.

Answer (score 0):

We are experimenting with bundling pnpm with Node.js. The bundled version is currently published as a separate package, you may install it using one of the following scripts:

```
curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.js | node - add --global @pnpm/beta
```

or using powershell:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest 'https://get.pnpm.io/v6.js' -UseBasicParsing).Content | node - add --global @pnpm/beta
```